# If subsequences of sequences of real numbers are uncountable then why are they represented as $\{x_{nk}\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I've noticed that subsequences of a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in real numbers are represented as $\{x_{nk}\}$. Why is this done when the subsequences of sequences of real numbers are uncountable?

Comment: $(x_{n_k})$ usually denotes a particular subsequence of $(x_n)$, not the collection of *all* subsequences. Perhaps you can show a concrete example where the notation $\{x_{nk}\}$ is used?

Comment: The notation doesn't mean the $k$-subsequence. It means we have $n_1<n_2<n_3<n_4$ and then we look at the subsequence whose first term is $x_{n_1}$, the next one is $x_{n_2}$ and so on.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the clarification.